# Problems when snapping two objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to align the intersection object and the road object. But when I used v and the move tool on my keyboard, they didn't match each other. The road object was moved far away from the intersection object so I guessed the problem here was because of the intersection object, the original image was a square so the road moved to its apexes. How can I fix this? and sorry about my grammar, it isn't good.
the image of problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsIuh.png
the intersection object
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmbOg.png

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually use snap functions, because I prefer to change the transform manually.  To align them it is enough that the position x is the same for both.  If you want something more automatic, you can quickly create an editor script that positions it automatically.

If I helped you, you can thank me accepting this answer :)
Good work!